GCE shielded VM boot integrity events with missing policy measurements
Occasionally we're seeing GCE IntegrityEvents with policyEvaluationPassed: false for Shielded VMs. According to https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/integrity-monitoring#diagnosing-failure, the policy evaluation will fail if the actualMeasurements and policyMeasurements differ. In these cases, however, there are no policyMeasurements:
{
  "insertId": "1",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent",
    "bootCounter": "1",
    "earlyBootReportEvent": {
      "policyEvaluationPassed": false,
      "actualMeasurements": [
        {
          "value": "0KUbR/mg3+8bwW0xjQtbxWh/1gI=",
          "pcrNum": "PCR_0",
          "hashAlgo": "SHA1"
        },
        // ...
      ],
      "policyMeasurements": []
    }
  },
  // ...
}

This happens very rarely (we have several hundred VMs boot per day and this happens maybe once a month). We've never manually updated the policy baseline. Why would policyMeasurements be missing? Is this a GCP bug?
